# How to play a beep sound when time is less than 10 seconds

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a countdown timer. I want to play a beep sound when time is less than 10 seconds. Here is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/Eddamoun/591mcbry/1/

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
        var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
        setInterval(function () {
            minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
            seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

            minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
            seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

            display.text("00 : " + minutes + " : " + seconds);

            // Not working!
            if (--timer < 10) {
                var audio = new Audio('beep.mp3');
                audio.play();
            }

            if (--timer < 0) {
                window.location.href = "test.php";
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    jQuery(function ($) {
        var testtime = 60 * 1,
            display = $('#time');
        startTimer(testtime, display);
    });
```

Comment: Just add the `jquery lib` https://jsfiddle.net/kjr1spbo/

Comment: Fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/fvsp5Ld7/ (you were decrementing `timer` twice, btw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys, the problem was solved! My browser was blocking websites from playing sounds. The code is working now with little modification:

```
**// Not working!**
        if (--timer < 10) {
            var audio = new Audio('beep.mp3');
            audio.play();
        }

**// working!**
        if (timer < 10) {
            var audio = new Audio('beep.mp3');
            audio.play();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you had load the jquery into your scope,those codes could work after the window loaded.
But you should  change codes 
`var audio = new Audio('beep.mp3');
                audio.play();`;
Maybe you can define a global variable `var audio`,when the audio was initialized,you can skip the `new Audio()`.